# Get managed devices from specific user in Graph Api?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Im trying to get a specific users managed devices using microsofts graph api. How can I write this? I cant find any documentation on this specific case? I am sending the request as the application and not the user so I guess I cannot use .Me.ManagedDevices in this case? Im getting the error "Forbidden" when I try this.

```
        public async Task<String> GraphAsync()
        {
            List<Microsoft.Graph.QueryOption> options = new List<Microsoft.Graph.QueryOption>
            {
                new Microsoft.Graph.QueryOption("$userId", "e984122-28d0-46ba-8e1f-40cf75d405d9")
            };



            try
            {
               var graphClient = ClientFactory.GetGraphApiClient();
               var graphResult = await graphClient.Users.ManagedDevices.Request(options).GetAsync();

                return graphResult[0].DisplayName;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedException(e + "Error calling GraphClient.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to use application permission to [get managedDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-get?view=graph-rest-1.0).

[image]

By the way, you can not use `.Me` if you are using application way.

Answer (score 0):

I actually needed to use the token for the user instead and then I could use .Me